# FFmpeg + iOS + lossy cellular connections

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am able to play an RTMP audio + video real-time stream on iOS with FFmpeg. Works fantastic when everything is on a solid WiFi connection.

When I switch to a cellular connection (great signal strength and LTE/4G), `av_read_frame()` will intermittently block for an unacceptable amount of time. From what I can tell, it's not that the cellular data connection just dropped, because I can reconnect immediately and start downloading more packets. In some cases, I've clocked 30+ seconds of hang time before it returns the next frame. When the next frame finally comes in, my real-time video stream is permanently delayed by the amount of time that `av_read_frame()` blocked.

I attempted a work-around by using the `AVIOInterruptCB` interrupt callback to abort `av_read_frame()` if the function takes longer than 1 second to return.  Here's what that code looks like:

```
- (void)readPackets {
    // Make sure FFmpeg calls our interrupt periodically
    _context->interrupt_callback.callback = interrupt_cb;
    _context->interrupt_callback.opaque = self;

    dispatch_async(_readPacketQueue, ^(void) {
        int err;

        while(true) {
            _readFrameTimeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
            err = av_read_frame(_context, &packet);
            _readFrameTimeStamp = 0;

            if(err) {
                // Error - Reconnect the entire stream from scratch, taking 5-10 seconds
                // And we know when av_read_frame() was aborted
                // because its error code is -1414092869 ("EXIT")
            }
            else {
                // Play this audio or video packet
            }
        }
   });
}

/**
 * Interrupt
 * @return 1 to abort the current operation
 */
static int interrupt_cb(void *decoder) {
    if(decoder) {
        if(_readFrameTimeStamp != 0) {
            if([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - _readFrameTimeStamp > 1) {
                // Abort av_read_frame(), it's taking longer than 1 second
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This definitely aborts `av_read_frame()` after 1 second, but unfortunately after I do this, future attempts to call `av_read_frame()` result in `EIO` errors (-5), which indicates that the connection has been severed.

As a result, I am forced to fully reconnect the viewer, which takes 5-10 seconds. (`avformat_open_input()` takes ~3-4 seconds, and then find the stream info again takes ~2-3 seconds, and then start reading frames).

The 5-10 second delay to fully reconnect is much better than waiting more than 10 seconds for `av_read_frame()` to unblock, and it's much better than the real-time stream being delayed by a significant amount.  But it's much worse than being able to retry av_read_frame() immediately.

From a cellular user's perspective, their video locks up intermittently for 5-10 seconds while we reconnect the stream in the background from scratch, which isn't a good user experience.

What strategies are there to better way to manage av_read_frame() on a lossy cellular connection? 
(Or strategies to improve the reconnect time?)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to move to your own handling of network I/O and feed avformat with data chunks.